# Tkinter Collision Between Objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm working on a small project (more of a game) and am completely stuck on **collision**. The game is pretty simple in that - there's a player (a blue block) that tries to get across the screen (using arrow keys) while trying to avoid the moving rectangles (up/down).

Here is what it looks like:
[image: game display]

I've tried the `canvas.coords()` method but I can't seem to get it to work properly. I have all the game logic in one file with a a couple classes, and the GUI is in another file with its own class.

```
from project.helpers import *


class Player:

    def __init__(self, x=100, y=200, color="blue"):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color

    def render(self, canvas):

        canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x+50, self.y+50, fill=self.color)

    def move_right(self):

        self.x += 10

    def move_left(self):

        self.x -= 10

    def move_up(self):

        self.y -= 10

    def move_down(self):

        self.y += 10

    def get_x(self):

        return self.x

    def get_y(self):

        return self.y


class Rectangles:

    def __init__(self, x=200, y=300, vel_y=randint(3, 10)):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.vel_y = vel_y
        self.color = get_random_color()

    def render(self, canvas):

        self.rect1 = canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x+50, self.y+200, fill=self.color)
        self.rect2 = canvas.create_rectangle(self.x+200, self.y, self.x+250, self.y+200, fill=self.color)
        self.rect3 = canvas.create_rectangle(self.x+400, self.y, self.x + 450, self.y+200, fill=self.color)
        self.rect4 = canvas.create_rectangle(self.x+600, self.y, self.x+650, self.y+200, fill=self.color)
        self.rect5 = canvas.create_rectangle(self.x+800, self.y, self.x+850, self.y+200, fill=self.color)

    def move(self, canvas):

        self.y += self.vel_y

        if self.y < 0 or self.y > canvas.winfo_height():  # top & bottom of canvas, don't need to change x
            self.vel_y = -self.vel_y

    def get_position(self, canvas):

        return canvas.coords(self.rect1)
```

```
from project.game import *
from tkinter import *


class App:

    def __init__(self, window, width=1200, height=600):

        # Get the classes from the other file so that we can use them in the animation method
        self.player = Player()
        self.block = Rectangles()

        # Set up canvas
        self.window = window
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.canvas = Canvas(window, width=self.width, height=self.height, bg="gray")
        self.canvas.pack()

        # Set up animation variables
        self.rate = 10
        self.terminated = True
        self.window.after(0, self.animation)

        # Create the control frame for buttons and bind the arrow keys to the process_keys method
        self.control_frame = Frame(window)
        self.control_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=2)
        self.canvas.bind("<Key>", self.process_keys)
        self.canvas.focus_set()

        # Welcome text that displays when module is first run, this disappears once the game has started
        self.welcome_text = self.canvas.create_text(600, 300, fill="red", font="Tahoma 24", text="Welcome! Press "
                                                                                                  "Start to "
                                                                                           "play game.")

        # Call the create_widgets method
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """Set up all buttons on the bottom of the GUI"""

        quit_button = Button(self.control_frame, text="Quit", command=self.quit)
        quit_button.pack(side=RIGHT)

        play_button = Button(self.control_frame, text="Start", command=self.start)
        play_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2)

    def start(self):
        """Once the user has clicked the Start button, call this method to begin the game - this will start the
        animation loop"""
        self.terminated = False

    def animation(self):
        """Create animation loop"""
        if not self.terminated:
            self.canvas.delete(ALL)
            self.player.render(self.canvas)  # Render the blue box (player) on to the canvas
            self.block.render(self.canvas)  # Render the colored rectangles (the enemies) on to the canvas
            self.block.move(self.canvas)  # Move the rectangles within the canvas boundaries

        self.window.after(self.rate, self.animation)

    def process_keys(self, event):
        """Set up arrow keys to correspond to the player movements (left, right, up, down)"""
        if event.keysym == "Right":
            self.player.move_right()
        if event.keysym == "Left":
            self.player.move_left()
        if event.keysym == "Up":
            self.player.move_up()
        if event.keysym == "Down":
            self.player.move_down()

    def quit(self):
        self.window.destroy()  # Once user has clicked the quit button, exit the GUI program


# Driver code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Avoid the blocks')
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to get it so that if I move the player with the arrow keys and I "collide" with one of the moving rectangles, a message gets printed on the canvas saying "game over".

Comment: Good question, but can you provide `self.create_widgets()` so I can run your program? I'm not much of a tkinter user, so apologies if this function is obvious/trivial.

Comment: Updated code to run

Comment: Unfortunately this got closed out. The duplicate question isn't very satisfying, but maybe do an edit to strip the code down to a minimal example that still reproduces the problem and I'll vote to reopen here. Having said that, collision between two rectangles is a pretty well-known and searchable topic. Good luck.